# LTO Ultrium 2 - free management software

Tags: backup, tape, lto

i'm making backup using ntbackup to write on LTO Ultrium 2 cartridges ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape-Open ).

All worked fine till last week when suddenly all cartridges are rejected (for backup) by the tape.
(Just a bit of information i tried the tape with a NEW cartridge and all going fine).

My question is: **is there a free/opensource software to check the health of my LTO Ultrium cartridges**?

*In another place where i worked we have to revalidate cartridges (LTO Ultirum 1) and retension them every year (using CA Brightstor).*

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you could provide the type and manufacturer of lto drive and the os, your
question would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [LTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape-Open) (the technology name) and [Ultrium](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/12169-304612-3446236-3446236-3446236-4150338.html?dnr=1) (a specific product name) interchangeably, which leads me to believe you're using an HP tape drive.

If using HP gear, you can try the *free* [HP Library and Tape Tools](http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/storageworks/ltt/) (HP L&TT) software to run diagnostics and media operations on your drive. [It's available for Windows](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?pnameOID=406731&locale=en_US&taskId=135&prodSeriesId=406729&prodTypeId=12169), as well as other operating systems.

There are other [management tools available for Quantum and IBM drives](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH176521), but try the HP software first, since the mechanics of other drives may be the similar.

Comment: I'm using the following cartridge: IBM "Total storage LTO Ultrium" on an IBM server i'll provide you tape model ASAP

Comment: Thank you for you contribution, however quoting wikipedia "The standard form-factor of LTO technology goes by the name Ultrium, the original version of which was released in 2000 and could hold 100 GB of data in a cartridge. A version released in 2010 can hold 1.5 TB in a cartridge of the same size." I believe Ultrium it's not HP Proprietary.

Comment: HP brands its drive models as Ultrium 448, Ultrium 920, Ultrium 1760 to denote LTO-2, LTO-3 and LTO-4 compatibility... So in common use, "LTO" is the generic, "Ultrium" usually refers to the HP variant.